# Does $x\in (S, \circ)$ mean the same thing as $x\in S$ where $ (S, \circ)$ is an algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

How should I interpret when one writes $x\in (S, \circ)$ where $(S, \circ)$ is an [algebraic structure](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Algebraic_Structure); $S$ being a set and $\circ$ being a binary operation defined on all elements of $S\times S\,?$

I asked it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) where I got the reply I should interpret it as $x\in S\,.$ It somewhat makes sense.

But why then $x\in S$ isn't simply used instead of $x\in (S,\circ)\,?$

Or does the latter convey more meaning than the former?

Comment: I could only imagine someone doing that to try and make their sentence shorter. Could you give an example of where you saw this?

Comment: @nex: $\mathsf{Pr}\infty\mathsf{fWiki}$ uses it a lot in defining, deriving things in order-theory and abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means $x \in S$.  With the additional information that we consider $S$ together with operation $\circ$. So, for example, if I then write $x \circ x$ it is understood that we are using this particular operation $\circ$.